# How to replace the original value of variable in HTML tag

Tags: ksh, html

I am facing some problems in replacing the value of a variable in a html tag in a unix box. Here are the details. Please help me in finding a solution.

```
#!/bin/ksh

count=5

line="<td>$count</td>"

echo "$line"
```

I am expecting the output to be `<td>5</td>` but I am getting the output as  `<td>$count</td>`.

I tried a lot to solve this but couldn't :(

Comment: Your likely problem is that `ksh` doesn't do variable expansion the same way `bash` does.

Comment: The script you posted does output `<td>5</td>`. Did you copy-paste the right script? How are you running it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on `ksh` but according to the [documentation](http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html), the following should work (if slightly clunky):

```
echo -n "<td>" 
echo -n ${count} 
echo "</td>
```